# Convert a JSON Object to Buffer and Buffer to JSON Object back

Tags: json, node.js, buffer

I have a JSON object and I'm converting it to a `Buffer` and doing some process here. Later I want to convert the same buffer data to convert to valid JSON object.

I'm working on Node V6.9.1

Below is the code I tried but I'm getting `[object object]` when I convert back to JSON and cannot open this object.

```
var obj = {
   key:'value',
   key:'value',
   key:'value',
   key:'value',
   key:'value'
}

var buf = new Buffer.from(obj.toString());

console.log('Real Buffer ' + buf);  //This prints --> Real Buffer <Buffer 5b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74>

var temp = buf.toString();

console.log('Buffer to String ' + buf);  //This prints --> Buffer to String [object Object]
```

So I tried to print whole object using inspect way

```
console.log('Full temp ' + require('util').inspect(buf, { depth: null }));  //This prints --> '[object object]' [not printing the obj like declared above]
```

If i try to read it like an array

```
 console.log(buf[0]);  // This prints --> [
```

I tried parsing also it throw `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 2`

I need to view it as real object like I created (I mean like declared above).

Please help..

Comment: `({"id":"value"}).toString() === '[object Object]'    //true`

Comment: `new Buffer()` is deprecated. See here: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_array

Answer (score 350, accepted):

You need to stringify the json, not calling `toString`

```
var buf = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

And for converting string to json obj :

```
var temp = JSON.parse(buf.toString());
```

Comment: This will not work if is there's another buffer field in `obj`

Comment: actually, toString is not needed here.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/hybuh7DbQkM

Comment: for me, it worked when I took away the JSON.stringify  and put the object directly inside the parameters, like so: var buf = Buffer.from({
   key:'value',
   key:'value',
   key:'value',
   key:'value',
   key:'value'
});

Comment: @JorgeMauricio Buffer.from() does not work with objects or (technically) arrays. That should be an error, but I think your object is getting converted to a string. In short, just use Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(...)) and JSON.parse(buffer.toString()) for simple objects. If, however, you have buffers stored in the object, you''l have to write a recursive function to walk to the bottom of the object, and convert all buffers to strings before you `stringify` the object into a buffer, then do the inverse on the other side

Comment: @Dzenly while `toString` is technically not needed, it should be used. Reading the page you linked, it states that the buffer is converted to a string (using Buffer.toString) using `utf8` encoding, and while normally this is not an issue, if the buffer was created in some other encoding, you will get garbage. So really, for things like this, it should be fine, but for a lot of other scenarios (where you have little to no control over things passed in), knowing and respecting the encoding is a must

Comment: Good point @werlious, plus `typescript` doesn't allow `JSON.parse(buffer)`

Answer (score 8):

[image]

**Kindly copy below snippet**

```
const jsonObject = {
        "Name":'Ram',
        "Age":'28',
        "Dept":'IT'
      }
      const encodedJsonObject = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(jsonObject)).toString('base64'); 
      console.log('--encodedJsonObject-->', encodedJsonObject)
      //Output     --encodedJsonObject--> eyJOYW1lIjoiUmFtIiwiQWdlIjoiMjgiLCJEZXB0IjoiSVQifQ==

      const decodedJsonObject = Buffer.from(encodedJsonObject, 'base64').toString('ascii'); 
      console.log('--decodedJsonObject-->', JSON.parse(decodedJsonObject))
      //Output     --decodedJsonObject--> {Name: 'Ram', Age: '28', Dept: 'IT'}
```

Answer (score 3):

as @Ebrahim you have to use first `JSON.stringify` to convert the JSON to string, and then you can convert it to a Buffer. But it's little bit risky to use `JSON.stringify` since it can break your app in case of self refrencing or circular referncing:

```
   var y={}
   y.a=y
   JSON.stringify(y) // Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

If you have such a risk, it better to use a safe stringify solution like this the npm module [safe-json-stringify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-json-stringify)

And then you have to do:

```
// convert to buffer:
const stringify = require('safe-json-stringify');
var buf = Buffer.from(stringify(obj));

// convert from buffer:
var temp = JSON.parse(buf.toString());
```