# child_process.spawn returning buffer object

Tags: node.js, buffer, child-process, spawn, jsonparser

```
const cp = require("child_process");

ls = cp.spawn("node", ["./scripts/test.js"]);

ls.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout": ${data}`);

    const result = data.toString();

  });
```

In `ls.stdout.on` i am getting data as buffer and if i do it to `data.toString()`
it gives me result like `"{evenNumberSum :8, oddNumberSum:6}"` but i want result as a JSON object i am not even able to parse this type of result can anyone give me a better way to get result from buffer

```
CurrentOutput:
<Buffer 7b 3a 6e 61 6d 65 3d 3e 22 4a 6f 68 6e 22 2c 20 3a 61 67 65 3d 3e 33 30 2c 20 3a 63 69 74 79 3d 3e 22 4e 65 77 20 59 6f 72 6b 22 7d 0a>


Required Output:
{evenNumberSum :8, oddNumberSum:6}
```

test.js

```
let result = {};
function add(val1, val2) {
  return val1 + val2;
}
result.evenNumbersSum = add(2, 4);
result.oddNumbersSum = add(1, 3);
result.mixNumbersSum = add(1, 2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What does `test.js` look like?

Comment: Does `Buffer.from` and `JSON.parse()` work for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951307/convert-a-json-object-to-buffer-and-buffer-to-json-object-back

Comment: @NathanBoaldin no it is not working in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what `test.js` looks like, but I was not able to reproduce this issue.

I am using the following code..

---

***--EDIT/DISCLAIMER--*** People are most likely downvoting this because the solution I provided uses `eval`.  To summarize:

- *YOU SHOULD USE `eval` AS LITTLE AS POSSIBLE* (in a perfect world, `eval` would never be used)
- ONLY USE IT ON ****TRUSTED**** strings (aka DO NOT USE `eval` ON USER SUPPLIED DATA!!! EVER.)

Considering the disclaimer above, the only way I could get this to work was:

***main.js:***

```js
const cp = require('child_process');

ls = cp.spawn('node', ['./test.js']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  const dataString = data.toString();
  const dataJson = eval(`(${dataString})`);

  console.log('Data as JSON  =', dataJson);
  console.log('evenNumberSum =', dataJson.evenNumberSum);
  console.log('oddNumberSum  =', dataJson.oddNumberSum);
});
```

***test.js:***

```js
console.log({ evenNumberSum: 8, oddNumberSum: 6 });
```

---

Which produces the following output:

```
Data as JSON  = { evenNumberSum: 8, oddNumberSum: 6 }
evenNumberSum = 8
oddNumberSum  = 6
```

Comment: yes you are correct it produces this output but typeof data gives string but i want object  and if your print it like  console.log('stdout', data) it will give you buffer

Comment: @SourabhLakhotiya I see what you're saying now.. I have updated my answer with a working solution. Please let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: thankyou it works for me . but what to do if in the above question i use the spawn method like cp.spawn( 'php' , [' ./test.php ' ] or for the .rb file or .py file in that and it is also the case that test file can return anything JSON or string or integer or array